# How to hover a shape in swiftUI and not the frame containing the shape

Tags: macos, hover, swiftui, shapes

Any idea on how to dismiss the hover event for areas that are not covered by a random shape?

Here is the code for the gif:

```
Circle()
  .fill(self.hover ? Color.blue : Color.red)
  .frame(width: 100, height:100)
  .clipShape(Circle())
  .onHover { _ in self.hover.toggle() }
```

`.onTapEvent` is able to distinguish frame from shape

[image]

Comment: I am afraid this will not work since NSTrackingArea was always about rectangular tracking areas.